# Como realizar evento scroll apenas quando clicar em determinado elemento?

Tags: jquery

Quando clico em qualquer lugar do site, faz a animação de rolagem para a div #texto_posicao.

Como fazer para que só quando clicar no elemento fazer a animação?

```
$(window).on("resize click",function(){
  $('html, body').stop();
   var abas = $(this).width() <= 800 ? "#texto_posicao" : ".abas";
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(abas).offset().top}, 300);
    $("#texto_posicao").addClass("classecss");

    var lastScrollTop = 0;
 $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if(st < lastScrollTop) {
     $("#texto_posicao").removeClass("classecss");
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
 });


});
```

html

```
<div class="abas abas1" tabindex="1">

Planejamento Estratégico
</div>
<div class="abas abas2" tabindex="2">
   Mentoria Food Service
</div>
<div class="abas abas3" tabindex="3">
   Terceirização Financeira
</div>
<div class="abas abas4" tabindex="4">
   Marketing Full Time
</div>
<div class="abas abas5" tabindex="5">
   Mastermind
</div>
<br clear="all" /><br />
```

Comment: cara, você colocou o evento click no `window`, dai você praticamente você setou o clique na janela inteira, você tem que colocar num elemento especifico

Comment: Wagner, poste o seu HTML para ficar mais fácil de ajudar. Mas basicamente é só colocar o elemento aba no lugar de `html,body` na `animation` mas poste seu HTML para facilitar a análise.

Comment: está na resposta o html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É preciso separar os eventos, e não colocar tudo aninhado. Crie um evento `click` apenas para as `.abas`:

```
$(window).on("resize",function(){
   $('html, body').stop();
   var abas = $(this).width() <= 800 ? "#texto_posicao" : ".abas";
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(abas).offset().top}, 300);
   $("#texto_posicao").addClass("classecss");
});

var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if(st < lastScrollTop) {
      $("#texto_posicao").removeClass("classecss");
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});

$(".abas").on('click', function() {
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#texto_posicao").offset().top}, 300);
   $("#texto_posicao").addClass("classecss");
});
```

Comment: dessa forma, não está adicionando a classe css aqui quando clica na aba $(window).on("resize",function(){
   $('html, body').stop();
   var abas = $(this).width() <= 800 ? "#texto_posicao" : ".abas";
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(abas).offset().top}, 300);
   $("#texto_posicao").addClass("classecss");
});

Comment: Quando clica na aba?

Comment: Se for quando clica na aba, atualizei a resposta. É só adicionar `$("#texto_posicao").addClass("classecss");` no onclick.

Answer (score 1):

Wagner, você está realizando o evento `resize e click` na janela do navegador, ou seja, sempre que houver o click na janela, será disparado o evento. Adicione o código dentro de um evento de click do elemento que você deseja que seja clicado para efetuar a animação.

```
$(window).on("resize",function(){
 $('seu-elemento').click(function(){
  $('html, body').stop();
   var abas = $(this).width() <= 800 ? "#texto_posicao" : ".abas";
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(abas).offset().top}, 300);
    $("#texto_posicao").addClass("classecss");
  }):
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
 $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if(st < lastScrollTop) {
     $("#texto_posicao").removeClass("classecss");
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;     
 });
});
```

Segue um exemplo simples de como funcionaria o seu evento.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#elemento1').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elemento2").offset().top
        }, 1000);
 })
 
})
```

```html
<div id="elemento1"> clique para descer<div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="elemento2"> Elemento alvo<div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: fiz assim mais nao deu certo  $('#texto_posicao').on('scroll', function() {

Comment: Na verdade, você tem que atribuir o evento de click ao elemento que você deseja que seja disparado o evento, como mostra na minha resposta. Ficaria assim `$('elemento').click(function(){ 
 //executa a ação de scroll })`

Comment: Teste o exemplo que adicionei na minha resposta.